# How is the last else block able to alternate between multiplying by 3 and adding by 5

Tags: javascript

I've been reading eloquent JavaScript, and the code below is a solution to a question in the chapter explaining recursion.

"Consider this puzzle: by starting from the number 1 and
repeatedly either
adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite set of numbers can be produced. How
would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a sequence of
such additions and multiplications that produces that number?"

```
function findSolution(target) {
    function find(current, history) {
        if (current == target) {
        return history;
        } else if (current > target) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) 
            ||
          find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
          }
        }
       return find(1, "1");
      }
console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how the last else block is able to alternate between multiplying by 3 and adding by 5
I know || means it'll take it's first truthy value, from the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should notice that non-empty strings are truthy and null is falsy. Now, let's consider what happens if `find(current + 5, ...)` actually finds a match. It'll return a string with the solution, which the `findSolution` function will return. If it doesn't find a match, it'll return `null`, which means the `||` continues on to `find(current * 3, ...)`, and if it finds a match there, it'll return the string with the solution, otherwise it'll return `null`. Basically, it's not alternating, it's just trying both and returning whichever one succeeds. It just looks like it's alternating since 24 is special.